# Overlay on video loop. I

Tags: loops, header, overlay

I need to add a slightly black overlay on my video loop on my website to later add Text and make the text more visible.

I'm very new to this and having trouble finding a solution. I tried various codes but as I said I'm having trouble.

```
<video  playsinline autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/Musikvideo_Vers3-Website.mp4">
        
 
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```